# Inivitation token sent in an email is differnt from the inviation token in the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, devise-invitable

I am on rails 4.0 . I am using devise 3.4.1 and devise_intitable gem 1.4.0 to send invitation to the users.
All works fine and users are able to accept invitation.but the problem is that the intiation toke in the url is not matching with the invitation_token store in the database.

Below is my code to send invitation

```
<%= link_to 'Change my password', edit_password_url(@resource, :reset_password_token => @token) %>
```

So i just want to know how devise is able to find the user from the database on the basis of invitation_token store in the database even if the invitation_token in the url is not matching with the invitation_token store in the database.

Thanks,